# How to share PowerApps with all user of Organization?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

I have created PowerApp and used SharePoint as a data source.

I need to share that PowerApp with all users of my Organization.

I have shared that app with Everyone as suggested in [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app) documentation.

But the app is not shared with everyone in my organization.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: so only some of all can see the app? and others do not?

Comment: If the user is a co-owner then the user can see that app. If the app is shared with a specific user then the user also accesses the app. But if shared with everyone then All users can not see that app.

Comment: After adding Everyone to the app permissions have a user go to web.powerapps.com > Apps > Shared with Me and see if the App shows up there. If it is there then the issue could be with your data source because most data sources manage permissions separately from PowerApps.  [Ref](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Sharing-app-with-Everyone-does-NOT-work/td-p/355276#:~:text=After%20adding%20Everyone%20to%20the,manage%20permissions%20separately%20from%20PowerApps.)

Comment: Perfect. I will add my comment as answer. Please mark it as solved would help me get points as well :)

Comment: If the users select "Org apps" instead of "My app" then users can see that shared app. I have shared an app with Everyone from PowerApps. Also, I need to give permission to users of the SharePoint site which contains the lists of PowerApps data. Thanks

Comment: So it looks like apps shared with Everyone in the organization actually show up under web.powerapps.com > Apps > Org Apps. On the mobile version of Powerapps, selecting All Apps seems to do the job. - This is right answer so please update that as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding Everyone to the app permissions have a user go to web.powerapps.com > Apps > Shared with Me and see if the App shows up there. If it is there then the issue could be with your data source because most data sources manage permissions separately from PowerApps.

If the users select "Org apps" instead of "My app" then users can see that shared app. I have shared an app with Everyone from PowerApps. Also, I need to give permission to users of the SharePoint site which contains the lists of PowerApps data

apps shared with Everyone in the organization actually show up under web.powerapps.com > Apps > Org Apps. On the mobile version of Powerapps, selecting All Apps seems to do the job

[Addition Article Link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Sharing-app-with-Everyone-does-NOT-work/td-p/355276#:%7E:text=After%20adding%20Everyone%20to%20the,manage%20permissions%20separately%20from%20PowerApps.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you get an error message for share with everyone? You will get a message like following if success

[image]

Comment: Yes, I got the success message same as you shared in the above image.

Comment: If the user is a co-owner then the user can see that app. If the app is shared with a specific user then the user also accesses the app. But if shared with everyone then All users can not see that app.